# Android custom menu icon not showing

Tags: android, menu, icons, menuitem

I am unable to use my custom icon instead of standard 3 dots menu icon. Here is what I have:

menu_editor.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemes.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.sunnyvalleystudio.notetakingapp.EditorActivity"
    >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_delete"
        android:title="@string/action_delete"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
    <!--to show it in menu we need to change "never" to "always -->
</menu>
```

EditorActivity.java

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        //inflate the menus - adds items to the action bar menu if it is present
        //MenuInflater gets the menu items from an existing XML file

        //to display delete icon only in the existing notes
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_EDIT)){
            MenuInflater inflater =  getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_editor, menu);

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Despite this I am still getting 3 dots icon with "Delete" position in its list. Why isn't the ic_action_delete icon showing? It is in the Assets. I am using Nexus 5 API 19 emulator.

Comment: What folder is it in specifically? And what format is the icon?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your package name (com.sunnyvalleystudio.notetakingapp.) before "R.menu.menu_editor" in inflate() the method and return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);